# Are the CRM error codes and associated descriptions available as part of the database?

Tags: import, dynamics-crm-2011, error-code

I am in the process of using the Import tool of CRM 2011 to get some legacy data migrated into a new CRM system. The failures that are reported of part of an Import contain a variety of reasons as to why the given source row failed. You can export error rows, but it exports EVERY row that was in error. This is irrespective of if you use that checkbox thing down the left hand side (what is that for anyway).

So I'm now resorting to the underlying database (again) and the error codes are listed there against each row. I'd just like to know if the error message is listed somewhere in the CRM tables as currently all I have is a integer that corresponds to the codes listed [on this site](http://www.cub-e.net/post/Microosft-Dynamics-CRM-Error-Code-List.aspx)

The query I'm mucking about with at the moment is similar to;

```
SELECT HeaderColumn, ColumnValue, SequenceNumber, ErrorNumber 
  FROM importlogbase 
 WHERE ImportFileId = 'E07F8495-302B-E311-BD4D-005056818306'
   AND ErrorNumber = -2147220653
ORDER BY SequenceNumber
```

Is there any table within CRM that I can join to that will give me the associated error message for the above error number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error definitions are not stored inside the CRM database.
You can find a list of the error codes (and a C# helper class (`errorcodes.cs`) inside the [CRM 2011 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004):

```
samplecode\cs\helpercode
```